# R update if statement to add count

Tags: r, if-statement, count, counter

I'm trying to count how columns contain text per row. I have the following that tells me if all columns contain text:

```
df = structure(list(Participant = 1:3, A = c("char", "foo", ""), B = c("char2", 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Participant", "A", "B"), row.names = c(NA,                                                                                                                        -3L), class = "data.frame")

 df$newcolumn <- ifelse(nchar(df$A)>1 & nchar(df$B)>1, "yes", "no")
```

Instead of "Yes" or "No" I want a count of how many matches occur. Ideas?

Comment: Could you update with the expected output as I have a doubt whether you meant the count of `nchar` or something else.

Comment: Also, please clarify meaning of "text". All elements in a data frame column will be of the same class. So you will always have the same number of "character" elements in every row of a data frame.

Comment: `B = c("char2", 0L, 0L)` doesn't make any sense, `0L` are gonna get converted to character `"0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your logic you can try something like the following:

```
df$newcolumn <- (nchar(df$A)>1) + (nchar(df$B)>1)

df
  Participant    A     B newcolumn
1           1 char char2         2
2           2  foo     0         1
3           3          0         0
```

Answer (score 1):

If we need to get the `nchar` per row, loop through the columns of interest, get the `nchar`, and use `Reduce` with `+` to get the sum per each row

```
df$CountNChar <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(df[-1], nchar))
```

Or if we need the `sum` of logical condition, just change the `nchar` to `nchar(x) > 1` (with anonymous function call)

```
df$CountNChar <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(df[-1], function(x) nchar(x) >1))
df$CountNChar
#[1] 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to count the number of rows where`df$A` and `df$B` have more than one character in them. The easiest way to do this is with `sum`, since `logical` vectors can be added up just like `numeric` or `integer`. Thus, the code fragment you want is

`sum(nchar(df$A)>1 & nchar(df$B)>1)`

However, looking at your first sentence, you should be aware that only one type of data can exist in a column of a data frame. `c("foo",0L,0L)` is a vector of class "character", with elements `"foo","0","0"`.